# Recommended values for DIPR configuration on a web-server

Tags: iis, ddos

Microsoft has this great [module](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions) for IIS server:

> **The Dynamic IP Restrictions** (DIPR) module for IIS 7.0 and above
>   provides protection against denial of service and brute force attacks
>   on web servers and web sites. **The module
>   temporarily blocks IP addresses of HTTP clients that make an unusually
>   high number of concurrent requests or that make a large number of
>   requests over small period of time.**

The default values are:

```
- Deny IP address for 5 concurrent requests
- Deny IP address for 20 requests in 200 milliseconds
```

[image]

**I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations on these values?** I'm not a server admin, I'm a developer without any security background...

PS. By the way, when a browser requests a web page, doesn't it make concurrent requests? For all the images/css/js fils on the page...

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looks for the answer - default values are quite restrictive - today they usually lead to 502 errors when loading resources (it depends on a website design).

I suggest to use:
maxConcurrentRequests="50"
maxRequests="200" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="500"

It still provides some security but allows to avoid errors which are not being properly logged, so they are not easy to be related to dynamic IP security settings.